# Swipe Through Multiple View

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I'm try to listen action like in game Word Connect.
They can listen action swipe multiple view like in picture : it from H -> O -> N.
I can listen action of a single view : onClick, onTouch,.. but with multiple view,i cant.
How can i do that? Thanks in advance.
[A picture of WordConnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7w5O.jpg)

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Organise the views you want in a viewGroup and enable the following property:

```
ViewGroup.setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(true);
```

or add `android:splitMotionEvents=“true”` in your layout.xml. Then set your onTouch listener to all your views, and add your code for each view. The property above will trigger a touch event with every view that the user touches.

Comment: Thanks u. I want to ask you more question. My ImageView in a FrameLayout and this FrameLayout in a LinearLayout. Where should I put android:splitMotionEvents=“true”? in FrameLayout or LinearLayout

Comment: @LongNguyen you can put it in the direct parent of the views between which you want to split your motion events. for your imageView the FrameLayout should work.